# client_side_validations gem anche conditional validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, client-side-validation

First of all I'm working on a rails 3.2 app and I'm using client_side_validation gem.
Is there a way from js to enable/disable the validation of certain fields? I need a conditional validation depending on a select input.
Do i need to fallback on server-side validation?